# DNS CNAME & MX wildcard

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I'm using all infrastructure on AWS and I need:

```
mydomain.com A ALIAS {S3-bucket- > } s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.
www.mydomain.com CNAME mydomain.com
  -> website on Amazon S3


*.mydomain.com CNAME {beanstalk} -> myserver-app.elasticbeanstalk.com
    -> all other subdomains redirect to the Amazon Beanstalk app


*.mydomain.com MX ->
         10 XXYY.in1.mandrillapp.com.
         20 XXYY.in2.mandrillapp.com.
         -> all emails goes to mandrillapp.
```

How is possible to do it?

As it's written it doesn't work because of CNAME vs. MX wildcards.

I can't use all names because subdomains will be generated dynamically.

Thank you a lot!!

David

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly isn't working? What is the exact issue you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found, you can't have a `CNAME` and any other type of record at the same level of the DNS hierarchy.  [Route 53 Alias records](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html), which you're using for your bare domain and for `www` were created to work around this limitation in the design of DNS, and don't have the same incompatibility issue... but the target of an `Alias` record can only be one of four things, at the moment: a CloudFront distribution, an Elastic Load Balancer, an S3 bucket of the same name as the hostname in the A record, or another record of the same type in the same hosted zone.

The last two won't help you, but either of the first two could.

If your beanstalk application already has an ELB, you can find that name under Load Balancers in the EC2 console, and you should be able to just use that as your Alias target for the `*` wildcard A-record Alias for your domain.  Or, you could add a load balancer to your beanstalk app, for this purpose.

Alternately, you can create a CloudFront distribution, and configure myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com as the "custom origin" server for the distribition.  Configure what CloudFront calls an ["alternate domain name (CNAME)"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) in the distribution for `*.example.com` -- and, incidentally, disregard the fact that the CloudFront console calls it a "CNAME."  They can also be used as Alias targets.  Configure the distribution to [forward the incoming `Host:` header](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders) to the origin, as well as any other headers you want to forward.  Then, you should be able to create your wildcard Alias A record, pointing to the CloudFront distribution, which will forward requests to the beanstalk app.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is an issue with the [rules of DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), which forbid a CNAME record where another record exists.

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
> present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
> cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
> used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

Is there are particular reason that you want to have a wildcard MX record? I can't see any situation where it provides a benefit, yet many where it would be a very bad idea! (particularly it makes any host on the network a viable target to send spam from, as any host on that can resolve to the domain has permission to send.

If you explicitly name your MX records you can have a CNAME wildcard (actually I might need to check that! but I do believe so)

Comment: yes I need it - it's for an app that clients can you their own emails as [user]@[companyname].mydomain.com